# What am I missing in this Sudoku?

Tags: sudoku

I think I am missing something in the instance below, since I could solve it only with a long-winded chain of deductions starting with the assumption that (coordinates are (row,column)):

> 8 is in (8,7),

and continuing as follows:

> => 8 is in (7,6)
>  => 9 is in (1,4)
>  => 9 is in (5,5)
>  => 9 is in (4,1)
>  => 9 is in (7,3)
>  => 3 is in (9,2)
>  => 3 is in (8,7)

a contradiction.

I just started learning Sudoku and it never happened before to have to do this, so maybe I am missing something, or I am not aware of a simple(r) technique applicable in this instance.

[image]

EDIT:

- Coordinates are (row,column), **starting with the upper left square which is (1,1)**;
- Candidates for a number in a box are filled in only if there are at most two of them. With the exception of 3 and 8 in the bottom-center box, that are filled in even if there are 3 candidates.

Comment: Which site is this Sudoku from?

Comment: It is from an app aptly called "Sudoku"

Comment: You may want to double check your candidate numbers, they are not complete or consistent. For instance, the bottom-left of the center box could be a "9" but this is not listed.

Comment: @Mikey You are right, I should have specified the criteria I used to fill in the candidates: they are there only if there are at most 2 candidates of a given number in a box. In the center box, as you notice, there are three cells 9 can be in, so I didn't fill it in. The exception is the bottom-center box, where 3 and 8 are filled in, even if there are more than 2 squares they can be in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deduce:

> Cell (1,6) must be an 8.
>
>  The reason is that the rows and columns of (1,6) contain 2345679 leaving only 1 and 8 as possibilities.  But if you look at the upper left sector, the 1 must be in one of the top two cells, because the other 2 cells cannot be 1.  Therefore, since 1 must be in either (1,1) or (1,2), (1,6) can not be a 1.  This leaves 8 as the only possibility.
>
>  From, there, cell (7,6) must be a 3.  I didn't keep going after that.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach:

> 8 in (7,6) => 9 in (7,1) and 3 in (7,3), which disagrees with (4,1)=9.

The logic bit:

> Row 7 should read (389)4(389) | (56)(56)(389) | 721, but (2,1), (2,3) and (9,6) mean that it becomes (89)4(39) | (56)(56)(38) | 721. So, 8 in (7,6) makes (7,1)=9 and (7,3)=3.
>
>  The (56) is forced by the 5 and 6 in row 8 and column 6, and the 3 filled cells on row 9 in block {3,2}.
>
>  To summarize, if (7,6)=8, then (4,1)=9, which removes all candidates from (7,1).

You can remove some of your original logic by noticing a contradiction on row 7:

> 9 in (4,1) means (7,1) is 8, but so is (7,6).

Another way:

> Let (7,1)=9. Then {(4,1),(4,2)}={2,7}, so (4,7)=9 -> (6,4)=9 -> (1,5)=9 -> (1,6)=8 -> (7,6)=3, which means (7,3) is stranded.

Finally, but a bit sneaky:

> The 5,6 in block {3,2} is forced, and 5 in block {1,2} is in the middle row, so the 6 must be on top in that block (assuming that the Sudoku has a unique solution), which makes (2,2)=6.

Comment: Actually, if 8 in (7,6) then 9 in (7,3) follows. Thank you for your answer, I know it's hard to follow, that's why I'm asking if there was some other easier fact I was missing.

Comment: Wait, I think your first 2 spoilers are assuming my candidates are row/column-wise, but actually they are *box*-wise (that's why you find contradictions). The third spoiler is interesting, but I can't understand why, if 5 is in the middle row of {1,2}, then I can conclude that 6 is in its upper row.